# Run An R Script Continuosly on The Cloud

Tags: r

Currently, I have an R script where my computer wakes up every hour to run the code. The way I am doing this is by creating a bash file that runs my R script. I was wondering if there is a way to do this on the cloud. It seems like RstudioCloud does not support this feature.

From reading some articles, it seems like the consensus is to use Microsoft Azure virtual machine. Would you agree with this? I was hoping for a much simpler solution. Something like RstudioCloud where I can just open up a script and run the code.

I have a web application that pulls from a mongoDB. However, the data in the mongoDB needs to be updated every hour. So instead of using my local machine (currently doing), it would be much nicer to use the cloud.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Personally I use `cronicle`, https://github.com/jhuckaby/Cronicle. Once you set it up on your `unix` box its very user friendly